# tcolorbox Title positionning and box size

Tags: positioning, titles, tcolorbox

I'm working on remaking a custom class for my lessons. I had an old one using TikZ that allowed me to have this behavior:

[image]

But it was buggy and did not allow for breakable environments.

I am now trying to remake everything using `tcolorbox` but the code I found produces this:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```latex
\newlength{\mylen}
\newlength{\hauteur}
\settowidth{\mylen}{Méthode}
\setlength{\hauteur}{\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\hauteur}{0.5mm}

\newtcbtheorem{methode}{Méthode :}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    coltitle=eggplant, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    detach title,
    opacityfill=0,
    frame hidden,
    %left=\dimexpr\textwidth-\mylen\relax,
    %top=0mm,
    %boxsep=0mm,
    borderline west = {0.5pt}{0pt}{},
    overlay unbroken and first={
        \node[xshift=-\mylen,yshift=-\hauteur] at (frame.north west) {\tcbtitle};
    }
}{meth}
```

The `sidebyside` option could work but it does not allow breakable environments, could someone point me in the right direction?

Edit : As asked here is some compilable code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{extreport}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{arev}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\newlength{\mylen}
\newlength{\hauteur}
\newlength{\malongueur}
\settowidth{\mylen}{Méthode :}
\setlength{\hauteur}{\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\hauteur}{0.5mm}
\settowidth{\malongueur}{408.52pt}
%\addtolength{\malongueur}{-\mylen}

%définition des couleurs
\definecolor{blueslategray}{cmyk}{0.189, 0.091, 0, 0.439}
\definecolor{greenbrown}{HTML}{555544}
\definecolor{cottonseed}{cmyk}{0, 0.026, 0.047, 0.255}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.272, 0.068, 0, 0.192}
\definecolor{bluetrout}{cmyk}{0.18, 0.15, 0, 0.608}
\definecolor{brownred}{cmyk}{0, 0.531, 0.557, 0.239}
\definecolor{orangewhite}{cmyk}{0, 0.031, 0.075, 0.004}
\definecolor{avocado}{cmyk}{0.06, 0, 0.55, 0.37}
\definecolor{eggplant}{cmyk}{0.04, 0.24, 0, 0.47}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.12,0.47,0.87}

\newtcbtheorem{theoreme}{Théorème}{
    lower separated=false,
    colback=orangewhite,
    colframe=white, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=brownred,
    coltitle=orangewhite,
    coltext=brownred,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    boxed title style={colframe=greenbrown},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm},
}{theo}

\newtcbtheorem{methode}{Méthode :}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    coltitle=eggplant, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    detach title,
    opacityfill=0,
    frame hidden,
    %left=30mm,
    %top=0mm,
    %boxsep=0mm,
    borderline west = {0.5pt}{0pt}{},
    overlay unbroken and first={
        \node[xshift=-\mylen,yshift=-\hauteur] at (frame.north west) {\tcbtitle};
    }
}{meth}

\begin{document}
\begin{theoreme}{}{}
    du texte \textbf{texte} \dotfill
\end{theoreme}

\begin{methode*}{}{}
    du texte
\end{methode*}
\end{document}
```

Here is a 'working' version :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{extreport}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{arev}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\newlength{\mylen}
\newlength{\hauteur}
\newlength{\malongueur}
\settowidth{\mylen}{Méthode :}
\setlength{\hauteur}{\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\hauteur}{0.5mm}
\settowidth{\malongueur}{408.52pt}
%\addtolength{\malongueur}{-\mylen}

%définition des couleurs
\definecolor{blueslategray}{cmyk}{0.189, 0.091, 0, 0.439}
\definecolor{greenbrown}{HTML}{555544}
\definecolor{cottonseed}{cmyk}{0, 0.026, 0.047, 0.255}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.272, 0.068, 0, 0.192}
\definecolor{bluetrout}{cmyk}{0.18, 0.15, 0, 0.608}
\definecolor{brownred}{cmyk}{0, 0.531, 0.557, 0.239}
\definecolor{orangewhite}{cmyk}{0, 0.031, 0.075, 0.004}
\definecolor{avocado}{cmyk}{0.06, 0, 0.55, 0.37}
\definecolor{eggplant}{cmyk}{0.04, 0.24, 0, 0.47}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.12,0.47,0.87}

\newtcbtheorem{theoreme}{Théorème}{
    lower separated=false,
    colback=orangewhite,
    colframe=white, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=brownred,
    coltitle=orangewhite,
    coltext=brownred,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    boxed title style={colframe=greenbrown},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm},
}{theo}

\newtcbtheorem{methode}{Méthode :}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    coltitle=eggplant, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    colbacktitle=white,
    detach title,
    opacityfill=0,
    frame hidden,
    left skip=1.55\mylen,
    left=0mm,
    top=0.3mm,
    toptitle=0mm,
    %boxsep=0mm,
    %attach boxed title to top left,
    %borderline west = {0.5pt}{0pt}{},
     overlay unbroken and first={
         \node[below left] at (interior.north west) {\tcbtitle};
     }
}{meth}

\newtcbtheorem{exemple}{Exemple :}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    coltitle=eggplant, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    colbacktitle=white,
    detach title,
    opacityfill=0,
    frame hidden,
    left skip=1.55\mylen,
    left=0mm,
    top=0.3mm,
    toptitle=0mm,
    %boxsep=0mm,
    %attach boxed title to top left,
    %borderline west = {0.5pt}{0pt}{},
     overlay unbroken and first={
         \node[below left] at (interior.north west) {\tcbtitle};
     }
}{exemp}

\begin{document}

\begin{theoreme}{}{}
dsds\dotfill
\end{theoreme}

\begin{methode*}{}{}
fkdlsmfkdlsm \dotfill
\lipsum
\end{methode*}

\begin{exemple*}{}{}
turlututu \lipsum
\end{exemple*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: I put some compilable code in the original post.

Comment: As I understand it, the method box doesn't have to fit in the margin, right? It's from the lengths you add `\mylen` and `\hauteur` and `\malongueur`. Delete that.

Comment: Do you insist on having the vertical rule in "second box"? IMHO it doesnt provide the nicest look and puts you in wrong direction (side-by-side boxes). If you dismiss that, you are actually almost done.

Comment: Ok I feel like I'm on the right way, I found out about left shift, the question would be to find the best way to compute the shifting values ans width values of the box so that everything stays coherent throughout the document.

Comment: @AndréC Yeah I want the left part out of the margin, but on the left hand side of the content of the box. That was the goal of those lengthes.
@TomášKruliš you mean putting 2 boxes side by side, not using the `sidebyside` option I suppose ?

Comment: You can shift the box to the right with the `left skip` key. And use `attach boxed title to top left` for the title, just define a style to remove its border.

Comment: @AndréC I'm using `left skip` now, the trouble is that finding out by how much I need to skip feels a bit like trials and error, I Don't know a consistant way of computing the skip for it to be aligned with other titles. Ideally The 'Méthode' should be aligned with 'Théorème' above.
And the `attach boxed title to top left` jus puts the text above the box not on the left side of it.

Comment: Can you add your partial solution ? That will be easy for us ? A french froggy math teacher too. ;-) :--)

Comment: Of course, I'll update the main post !
If you want I can upload the whole class somewhere too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code shows some modifications to OP's code to obtain a result more similar to original image.

Now Theorem environment has sharp corners, title attached without overlapping with text contents and border lines in right side and bottom.

In `example`, the `overlay` part has been modified to introduce the vertical line between title and contents. Similar solution could be applied to `methode` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{extreport}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{arev}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\newlength{\mylen}
\newlength{\hauteur}
\newlength{\malongueur}
\settowidth{\mylen}{Méthode :}
\setlength{\hauteur}{\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\hauteur}{0.5mm}
\settowidth{\malongueur}{408.52pt}
%\addtolength{\malongueur}{-\mylen}

%définition des couleurs
\definecolor{blueslategray}{cmyk}{0.189, 0.091, 0, 0.439}
\definecolor{greenbrown}{HTML}{555544}
\definecolor{cottonseed}{cmyk}{0, 0.026, 0.047, 0.255}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.272, 0.068, 0, 0.192}
\definecolor{bluetrout}{cmyk}{0.18, 0.15, 0, 0.608}
\definecolor{brownred}{cmyk}{0, 0.531, 0.557, 0.239}
\definecolor{orangewhite}{cmyk}{0, 0.031, 0.075, 0.004}
\definecolor{avocado}{cmyk}{0.06, 0, 0.55, 0.37}
\definecolor{eggplant}{cmyk}{0.04, 0.24, 0, 0.47}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.12,0.47,0.87}

\newtcbtheorem{theoreme}{Théorème}{
    lower separated=false,
    sharp corners,
    colback=orangewhite,
    colframe=brownred, 
    leftrule=0pt, toprule=0pt,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=brownred,
    coltitle=orangewhite,
    coltext=brownred,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    boxed title style={colframe=brownred, sharp corners},
    attach boxed title to top left,
}{theo}

\newtcbtheorem{methode}{Méthode :}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    coltitle=eggplant, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    colbacktitle=white,
    detach title,
    opacityfill=0,
    frame hidden,
    left skip=1.55\mylen,
    left=0mm,
    top=0.3mm,
    toptitle=0mm,
    %boxsep=0mm,
    %attach boxed title to top left,
    %borderline west = {0.5pt}{0pt}{},
     overlay unbroken and first={
         \node[below left] at (interior.north west) {\tcbtitle};
     }
}{meth}

\newtcbtheorem{exemple}{Exemple :}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    coltitle=eggplant, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    colbacktitle=white,
    detach title,
    opacityfill=0,
    frame hidden,
    left skip=1.55\mylen,
    left=0mm,
    top=0.3mm,
    toptitle=0mm,
    %boxsep=0mm,
    %attach boxed title to top left,
    %borderline west = {0.5pt}{0pt}{},
     overlay unbroken and first={
         \node[below left] at (interior.north west) {\tcbtitle};
         \draw[eggplant, line width=1.5pt] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west);
     },
     overlay middle and last={
         \draw[eggplant, line width=1.5pt] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west);
     }
}{exemp}

\begin{document}

\begin{theoreme}{}{}
dsds\dotfill
\end{theoreme}

\begin{methode*}{}{}
fkdlsmfkdlsm \dotfill
\lipsum
\end{methode*}

\begin{exemple*}{}{}
turlututu \lipsum
\end{exemple*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]